# Cloudformation in create stack error: "ELB cannot be attached to multiple subnets in the same AZ"

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, devops

I trying to build infrastracture with Cloudformation json template. When I added two Subnets and SubnetRouteTableAssociation in both availability zones that i need. But creating process failing to create Loadbalancers with error:

> CREATE_FAILED AWS::ElasticLoadBalancing::LoadBalancer Rest ELB cannot
>   be attached to multiple subnets in the same AZ.

Here is the Parameters of AZs:

```
"AZs" : {
            "Description" : "The list of AvailabilityZones.",
            "Type" : "CommaDelimitedList",
            "Default" : "us-east-1a,us-east-1c"
        }
```

Here is Resources of  Subnets, SubnetRouteTableAssociation in both availability zones and ElasticLoadBalancing of Rest:

```
"PublicSubnet1a" : {
      "Type" : "AWS::EC2::Subnet",
      "Properties" : {
        "VpcId" : { "Ref" : "VPC" },
        "CidrBlock" : "10.0.0.0/24",
        "AvailabilityZone": {
          "Fn::Select": ["1", { "Ref": "AZs" }]
        },
        "Tags" : [
          {"Key": "Name", "Value": {"Fn::Join": ["", ["Offering-", {"Ref": "Env"}, {"Ref": "EnvNum"}, "-VPC"]]}},
          {"Key" : "Network", "Value" : "Public" }
        ]
      }
    },
     "PublicSubnet1c" : {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::Subnet",
      "Properties": {
        "VpcId": { "Ref" : "VPC" },
        "CidrBlock": "10.0.1.0/24",
        "AvailabilityZone": {
          "Fn::Select": ["1", { "Ref": "AZs" }]
        },
        "Tags" : [
          {"Key": "Name", "Value": {"Fn::Join": ["", ["Offering-", {"Ref": "Env"}, {"Ref": "EnvNum"}, "-VPC"]]}},
          {"Key" : "Network", "Value" : "Public" }
        ]
      }
    },
"PublicSubnet1aRouteTableAssociation" : {
      "Type" : "AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation",
      "Properties" : {
        "SubnetId" : { "Ref" : "PublicSubnet1a" },
        "RouteTableId" : { "Ref" : "PublicRouteTable" }
      }
    },
    "PublicSubnet1cRouteTableAssociation" : {
      "Type" : "AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation",
      "Properties" : {
        "SubnetId" : { "Ref" : "PublicSubnet1c" },
        "RouteTableId" : { "Ref" : "PublicRouteTable" }
      }
    },
"RestELB" : {
        "Type" : "AWS::ElasticLoadBalancing::LoadBalancer",
        "DependsOn": "AttachGateway",
        "Properties": {
            "LoadBalancerName": {"Fn::Join": ["",["Rest-ELB-", {"Ref": "VPC"}]]},
            "CrossZone" : "true",
            "Subnets": [{ "Ref": "PublicSubnet1a" },{ "Ref": "PublicSubnet1c" }],
            "Listeners" : [
                {"LoadBalancerPort" : "80", "InstancePort" : "80","Protocol" : "HTTP"},
                {"LoadBalancerPort" : "6060", "InstancePort" : "6060","Protocol" : "HTTP"}
            ],
            "HealthCheck" : {
              "Target" : "HTTP:80/",
              "HealthyThreshold" : "3",
              "UnhealthyThreshold" : "5",
              "Interval" : "90",
              "Timeout" : "60"
            }
        }
    }
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
"PublicSubnet1a" : {
    ...
    "AvailabilityZone": {
      "Fn::Select": ["1", { "Ref": "AZs" }] // <---- selects index 1 from AZs list
    },
    ...
"PublicSubnet1c" : {
    ...
    "AvailabilityZone": {
      "Fn::Select": ["1", { "Ref": "AZs" }] // <---- selects the same index 1 from AZs list
    },
```

both of your subnets are selecting the same index from AZs list (see "FN::select" statement). Change the select statement for `PublicSubnet1a` to be

```
"Fn::Select": ["0", { "Ref": "AZs" }]
```

Comment: It still didn't helped me. I get the error: "The availability zones of the specified subnets and the AutoScalingGroup do not match"

Comment: @muzaparoff I've seen that you accepted the answer after you had written that it didn't help. Do you still have that problem?

Comment: It helped me to get another error about availability zones in Subnet and AutoscallingGroup. And I rapaired that too. So everything fine now. Thanks!

Comment: This error could also happen as described by http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/troubleshooting.html "Changing subnets on the load balancer requires moving it out of the original availability zone(s) and then back into the original with the desired subnets. During the process, all of your instances will be migrated between AZs, causing significant downtime. If you need to use different subnets, it's better just to create a new environment and perform a CNAME swap."